# Image title replace with current date

Tags: images, date

Currently, when uploading an image, Wordpress automatically uses the image name as image title. Is there a way to automatically use current date for the image title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using following code:

```
/* Automatically set the image Title, Alt-Text, Caption & Description upon upload
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
add_action( 'add_attachment', 'my_set_image_meta_upon_image_upload' );
function my_set_image_meta_upon_image_upload( $post_ID ) {

    // Check if uploaded file is an image, else do nothing

    if ( wp_attachment_is_image( $post_ID ) ) {

        $custom_title = date("Y-m-d"); //settings current date as title

        $my_image_details = get_post( $post_ID )->post_title;

        // Sanitize the title:  remove hyphens, underscores & extra spaces:
        $my_image_details = preg_replace( '%\s*[-_\s]+\s*%', ' ',  $my_image_title );

        // Sanitize the title:  capitalize first letter of every word (other letters lower case):
        $my_image_details = ucwords( strtolower( $my_image_title ) );

        // Create an array with the image meta (Title, Caption, Description) to be updated
        // Note:  comment out the Excerpt/Caption or Content/Description lines if not needed
        $my_image_meta = array(
            'ID'        => $post_ID,            // Specify the image (ID) to be updated
            'post_title'    => $custom_title ,      // Set image Title to date
            'post_excerpt'  => $my_image_details ,      // Set image Caption (Excerpt) to sanitized title
            'post_content'  => $my_image_details ,      // Set image Description (Content) to sanitized title
        );

        // Set the image Alt-Text
        update_post_meta( $post_ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', $my_image_title );

        // Set the image meta (e.g. Title, Excerpt, Content)
        wp_update_post( $my_image_meta );

    } 
}
```

Here I'm replacing image title with date and description with actual formatted title. This action will run every time you upload a new image.

Comment: Thank you!!! It worked perfectly!!

Comment: please mark the ans as accepted please.